# Writing fail case for ajax call in getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, getjson

I have following code of ajax call and I would like to write custom error on failed ajax call.In following piece of code block, where I can write the same:

```
$.getJSON("/ProductMatrix/CaptureCategoryTypeList/" + $("#categoryFilter > option:selected").attr("value"),
            function (data) {
                var items = "<option> Default  </option>";
                $.each(data,
                    function (i, captureCategoryType) {
                        items += "<option value=' " + captureCategoryType.Value + "'>" + captureCategoryType.Text + "</option>";
                    });
                $("#categoryTypeFilter").html(items);
                SherlockAdmin.Shared.closeProcessingWheel();
            });
```

Comment: `$.getJSON(... , function (data) { .... }).fail(function (result) { // do something });`

Comment: Thanks Stephen ! It worked like charm !

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "example.json", function() {
  console.log( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    console.log( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
  });

// Perform other work here ...

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.complete(function() {
  console.log( "second complete" );
});
```

Code from http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/